# Проверка на пустой input

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Есть `input type="text"` и `button`. Нужно сделать проверку: если в `input type="text"` введено более одного символа, то кнопка активна, если менее одного, то - неактивна.

```
<input type="text" id="text1">
<button id="btn"></button>
```

Comment: @NickVolynkin, лучшее решение, как можно модератора вызвать для подобных случаев? Только тревогу ставить?

Comment: @Other в чатик ответил - видно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например так:

```js
$('#text1').on('keyup',function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val();
  
  if(val.length >= 1){
    $('#btn').show(100);
  }else {
    $('#btn').hide(100);
  }
});
```

```css
#btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Попробуйте ввести в input что-нибудь. <br/>
<input type="text" id="text1">
  <button id="btn">button</button>
```

Comment: @Other в этом нет ничего плохого. Библиотеки были сделаны для упрощения работы - поэтому ничего страшного нет. И этот ответ вполне отвечает на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: @alexoander, плохого нет, хотя жикверисты, адепты поклонения `jQuery`, достали, но в метках нет тэгов библиотек, значит нужна ванилька.

Answer (score 13):

```js
function ctrlButton() {
  btn.disabled = this.value.trim().length === 0;
}

text1.addEventListener('input', ctrlButton, false);
ctrlButton.call(text1);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Кстати, можно и без JS обойтись

```css
#text1:invalid + #btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  /* для IE < 11 -- display: none; */
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1" pattern=".{1,}" required>
<button id="btn">Button</button>
```

Comment: К сожалению, данный код не подходит для моего случая. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в if было прописано "в поле ввода один или более символов"?

Comment: @A.Hall, там это и написано.